# "Incorrect code" when scanning QR in Android Messages for web

Tags: samsung, google, qr-code

I've installed [Android Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) in Samsung Galaxy S4 mini i9195 and it works fine, except one thing - it keeps complaining with an "Incorrect code" message whenever I try to scan the QR of https://messages.android.com

Everything else related to QR, like https://web.whatsapp.com, works perfectly for me. Is there any way to fix this? If not, I'll have to revert back to the built-in Messages app...

Comment: Same here. Identical problem. Did you ever work it out? Ive cleared all caches/data/uninstall/reinstall and no luck yet.

Comment: No news about it and you're the first to at least add a comment.